# How to copy files and directories from Windows to Linux

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ext3

I want to copy files from an NTFS windows filesystem creating the same directories and moving all files to an EXT3 filesystem.  Is there a way to do this using CLI safely and correctly? I can mount the NTFS filesystem available to Nautilus.  Using Fedora 21 OS.

Comment: Off topic, not a programming question. Ask on superuser instead

Comment: It will, I believe, require some scripting (programming) to actually achieve it.

Comment: Then you can write a script and do the job. If it doesn't work, ask specific programming questions.